# How to find and delete duplicate video (.mp4) files?

Tags: linux, files, find, video, file-comparison

I have 16,000+ short video clips and there are lots of them that are exactly alike to the human eye, but if you examine very closely you will find that one or the other may have an extra 1 second (or much much less) duration at the beginning or the end.

I have already tried several methods and had zero success in finding duplicates. You would think that comparing exact byte size would be good enough since bytes are so small. But no! The reason why not is because there may be a slight extra (or non-extra) few milliseconds in the beginning or end of the video clips. This causes them to be different and not identical, resulting in any duplicate finder using "byte for byte comparison" result no duplicate results.

And although the majority of the video clip is exactly like several others, nothing I use is finding any duplicates because of the few milliseconds difference at the beginning or at the end of the compared .mp4 files.

Does anyone know how I might find success in finding duplicates of these short video clip .mp4 files? On average they are about 30 seconds each, however its only a few milliseconds difference when compared closely to another. To the human eye this would be exactly the same, so I am seeing duplicates, but I don't want to have to watch and compare 16,000+ video clips all on my own.

Any suggestions?

---

**I found a great working answer to my question can you allow me to answer it?**

... seems I can't when it's put on hold ...

Comment: Kindly let us know you want to delete only the video whose size  and name is same right

Comment: Generating predictable thumbnails might be a decent idea: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/5315/14767

Comment: You haven't defined "exactly alike to the human eye" at all. Does that mean same clarity? Same starting frame?

Comment: @EvanCarroll No. It means that they are the same for the human eye.

Answer (score 3):

I too had the same problem, so I wrote [a program](https://github.com/gklc811/duplicate_video_finder).

The problem is that I had videos of various formats and resolution, so I needed to take a hash of each video frame and compare.

You can just change the directories at the top and you are good to go.

```py
from os import path, walk, makedirs, rename
from time import clock
from imagehash import average_hash
from PIL import Image
from cv2 import VideoCapture, CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT, CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CAP_PROP_FPS
from json import dump, load
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

input_vid_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\data\\'
json_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\db\\'
analyzed_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\analyzed\\'
duplicate_dir = r'C:\Users\gokul\Documents\duplicate\\'

if not path.exists(json_dir):
    makedirs(json_dir)

if not path.exists(analyzed_dir):
    makedirs(analyzed_dir)

if not path.exists(duplicate_dir):
    makedirs(duplicate_dir)


def write_to_json(filename, data):
    file_full_path = json_dir + filename + ".json"
    with open(file_full_path, 'w') as file_pointer:
        dump(data, file_pointer)
    return


def video_to_json(filename):
    file_full_path = input_vid_dir + filename
    start = clock()
    size = round(path.getsize(file_full_path) / 1024 / 1024, 2)
    video_pointer = VideoCapture(file_full_path)
    frame_count = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))
    width = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)))
    height = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    fps = int(VideoCapture.get(video_pointer, int(CAP_PROP_FPS)))
    success, image = video_pointer.read()
    video_hash = {}
    while success:
        frame_hash = average_hash(Image.fromarray(image))
        video_hash[str(frame_hash)] = filename
        success, image = video_pointer.read()
    stop = clock()
    time_taken = stop - start
    print("Time taken for ", file_full_path, " is : ", time_taken)
    data_dict = dict()
    data_dict['size'] = size
    data_dict['time_taken'] = time_taken
    data_dict['fps'] = fps
    data_dict['height'] = height
    data_dict['width'] = width
    data_dict['frame_count'] = frame_count
    data_dict['filename'] = filename
    data_dict['video_hash'] = video_hash
    write_to_json(filename, data_dict)
    return


def multiprocess_video_to_json():
    files = next(walk(input_vid_dir))[2]
    processes = cpu_count()
    print(processes)
    pool = Pool(processes)
    start = clock()
    pool.starmap_async(video_to_json, zip(files))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    stop = clock()
    print("Time Taken : ", stop - start)


def key_with_max_val(d):
    max_value = 0
    required_key = ""
    for k in d:
        if d[k] > max_value:
            max_value = d[k]
            required_key = k
    return required_key


def duplicate_analyzer():
    files = next(walk(json_dir))[2]
    data_dict = {}
    for file in files:
        filename = json_dir + file
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = load(f)
        video_hash = data['video_hash']
        count = 0
        duplicate_file_dict = dict()
        for key in video_hash:
            count += 1
            if key in data_dict:
                if data_dict[key] in duplicate_file_dict:
                    duplicate_file_dict[data_dict[key]] = duplicate_file_dict[data_dict[key]] + 1
                else:
                    duplicate_file_dict[data_dict[key]] = 1
            else:
                data_dict[key] = video_hash[key]
        if duplicate_file_dict:
            duplicate_file = key_with_max_val(duplicate_file_dict)
            duplicate_percentage = ((duplicate_file_dict[duplicate_file] / count) * 100)
            if duplicate_percentage > 50:
                file = file[:-5]
                print(file, " is dup of ", duplicate_file)
                src = analyzed_dir + file
                tgt = duplicate_dir + file
                if path.exists(src):
                    rename(src, tgt)
                # else:
                #     print("File already moved")


def mv_analyzed_file():
    files = next(walk(json_dir))[2]
    for filename in files:
        filename = filename[:-5]
        src = input_vid_dir + filename
        tgt = analyzed_dir + filename
        if path.exists(src):
            rename(src, tgt)
        # else:
        #     print("File already moved")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mv_analyzed_file()
    multiprocess_video_to_json()
    mv_analyzed_file()
    duplicate_analyzer()
```

Comment: Is this a python script for Windows?